# Fill in points on an already existing line in matlab

Tags: matlab, fill

Im trying to create a triangle wave in matlab with equal rise and fall slope.
I searched around abit and found a code example:

```
n=input ('Enter the length of the sequence N= ');
t=0:n;
y=(-1).^t; 
stem(t,y);
ylabel ('Amplitude');
xlabel ('Time Index');
TITLE ('Triangular waveform');
```

This code creates the the triangle form, but there are only data plots at the tip of each triangle. I want more data plots that follow the lines of the triangles.

Is there any function in matlab that can fill in data points with a specific width between the plots in the plotted lines from the graph? 
If no, how am I supposed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to linearly interpolate:

```
t2 = 0:0.5:n;
y2 = interp1(t, y, t2);
```

where `t` and `y` are the arrays from your example. You can use any size of interval for `t2`:

```
t2 = 0:0.1:n;
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

Change `t=0:n;` to `t=0:0.1:n;` and `y=(-1).^t;` to `y=2*abs(mod(t,2)-1)-1;`

This is what I got:

[image]